# How to make the same font size for both numerator and denominator?

Tags: pstricks, fontsize, pst-plot

As you can see below, the `3/2` looks so weird in which the font size of the numerator is bigger than that of  the denominator. How to make it get balanced?

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=0pt,12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-eucl}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\robustify\sqrt

\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}(-6,-1)(6,1.25)
    \pstGeonode[
        PointSymbol=|,
        PosAngle=-90,
        PointNameSep=16pt,
        PointName={\frac{3-\sqrt{17}}{2},-\frac{1}{2},\frac{3}{2},2,\frac{3+\sqrt{17}}{2}}
    ](-4,0){A}(-2,0){B}(0,0){C}(2,0){D}(4,0){E}
    \pcline[nodesep=-1](A)(E)
    \pcline(5.8,0)(E)\nbput{$++++$}
    \pcline(E)(D)\nbput{$----$}
    \pcline(D)(C)\nbput{$++++$}
    \pcline(C)(B)\nbput{$----$}
    \pcline(B)(A)\nbput{$++++$}
    \pcline(A)(-5.8,0)\nbput{$----$}
    \psset{arrows=*-*,offset=22pt}
    \pcline(A)(B)
    \pcline(C)(D)
    \pcline{*->}(E)(5.5,0)
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I find it hard to follow the picture when 1/2 = 2 :)

Comment: @JouleV: It is not such hard.

Comment: I noticed the bigger fractions first.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For reasons that depend on the same ones that force to `\robustify\sqrt`, a fraction as the first item is typeset incorrectly. You can `\robustify` also `\frac`.

```latex
\documentclass[pstricks,border=0pt,12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-eucl}
\usepackage{etoolbox,amsmath}
\robustify\sqrt
\robustify\frac

\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}(-6,-1)(6,1.25)
    \pstGeonode[
        PointSymbol=|,
        PosAngle=-90,
        PointNameSep=16pt,
        PointName={\frac{3-\sqrt{17}}{2},-\frac{1}{2},\frac{3}{2},2,\frac{3+\sqrt{17}}{2}}
    ](-4,0){A}(-2,0){B}(0,0){C}(2,0){D}(4,0){E}
    \pcline[nodesep=-1](A)(E)
    \pcline(5.8,0)(E)\nbput{${+}{+}{+}{+}$}
    \pcline(E)(D)\nbput{${-}{-}{-}{-}$}
    \pcline(D)(C)\nbput{${+}{+}{+}{+}$}
    \pcline(C)(B)\nbput{${-}{-}{-}{-}$}
    \pcline(B)(A)\nbput{${+}{+}{+}{+}$}
    \pcline(A)(-5.8,0)\nbput{${-}{-}{-}{-}$}
    \psset{arrows=*-*,offset=22pt}
    \pcline(A)(B)
    \pcline(C)(D)
    \pcline{*->}(E)(5.5,0)
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Also bracing each item works, but using a robust `\frac` is better.

Note: due to `+` and `-` being binary operation symbols, a sequence such as `++++` is interpreted as Ord Bin Ord Ord (by rule a binary operation symbol is changed into an ordinary one if it doesn't have suitable operands on either side) and the spacing is odd. Input them as `{+}{+}{+}{+}` and `{-}{-}{-}{-}` to get all ordinary symbols.

Answer (score 3):

It looks like a bug in `pst-eucl`. As a workaround, you can use  `\dfrac` instead (load  `amsmath`), and slightly increase the value of `PointNameSep`:

```
\documentclass[pstricks, border=0pt,12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-eucl}
\usepackage{amsmath, nccmath}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\robustify\sqrt

\begin{document}

\begin{pspicture}(-6,-1.25)(6,1.25)
    \pstGeonode[
        PointSymbol=|,
        PosAngle=-90,
        PointNameSep=18 pt,
        PointName={\dfrac{3-\sqrt{17}}{2},-\dfrac{1}{2},\dfrac{3}{2},2, \dfrac{3+\sqrt{17}}{2}}
    ](-4,0){A}(-2,0){B}(0,0){C}(2,0){D}(4,0){E}
    \pcline[nodesep=-1](A)(E)
    \pcline(5.8,0)(E)\nbput{$++++$}
    \pcline(E)(D)\nbput{$----$}
    \pcline(D)(C)\nbput{$++++$}
    \pcline(C)(B)\nbput{$----$}
    \pcline(B)(A)\nbput{$++++$}
    \pcline(A)(-5.8,0)\nbput{$----$}
    \psset{arrows=*-*,offset=22pt}
    \pcline(A)(B)
    \pcline(C)(D)
    \pcline{*->}(E)(5.5,0)
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: That is not a bug, it is a wrong use of `PointName`!

Answer (score 2):

It is *completely*  nonsense to use the `PointName` key for such labels because the label is internally also the node name. You should use simple nodes and `\psxTick` instead. However,

```
PointName={{\frac{3-\sqrt{17}}{2}},{-\frac{1}{2}},{\frac{3}{2}},{\scriptstyle2},{\frac{3+\sqrt{17}}{2}}}
```

should also do the trick

[image]

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=0pt,12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pstricks-add}

\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}(-6,-1)(6,1.25)
    \pnodes(-4,0){A}(-2,0){B}(0,0){C}(2,0){D}(4,0){E}
    \psxTick(-4){\frac{3-\sqrt{17}}{2}}
    \psxTick(-2){-\frac{1}{2}}
    \psxTick(0){\frac{3}{2}}
    \psxTick(2){\scriptstyle2\vphantom{\frac12}}
    \psxTick(4){\frac{3+\sqrt{17}}{2}}
    \multido{\rA=-4.9+4.0}{3}{\uput[90](\rA,0){$----$}}%
    \multido{\rA=-3+4}{3}{\uput[90](\rA,0){$++++$}}%
    \pcline[nodesep=-1.75](A)(E)
    \psset{arrows=*-*,offset=22pt}
    \pcline(A)(B)
    \pcline(C)(D)
    \pcline{*->}(E)(5.5,0)
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Or if you do not like hardcoded values:

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=0pt,12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pstricks-add}
\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}(-6,-1)(6,1.25)
    \pnodes(-4,0){A}(-2,0){B}(0,0){C}(2,0){D}(4,0){E}
    \psxTick(-4){\frac{3-\sqrt{17}}{2}}
    \psxTick(-2){-\frac{1}{2}}
    \psxTick(0){\frac{3}{2}}
    \psxTick(2){\scriptstyle2\vphantom{\frac12}}
    \psxTick(4){\frac{3+\sqrt{17}}{2}}
    \pcline[nodesep=-1.75](A)(E)
    \psset{arrows=*-*,offset=20pt}
    \pcline(A)(B)\nbput{$++++$}
    \pcline(C)(D)\nbput{$++++$}
    \pcline{*->}(E)(5.5,0)\nbput{$++++$}
    \psset{linestyle=none,arrows=-}
    \pcline(-5.8,0)(A)\nbput{$----$}
    \pcline(B)(C)\nbput{$----$}
    \pcline(D)(E)\nbput{$----$}
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```